# Conda doesn't upgrade to the latest version and CondaValueError: Key 'subdir' is not a known primitive parameter

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

My ultimate goal is to run the following command lines so that I can install numpy in my Mac M1 chip computer which has been problematic for many people ["note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip" message when trying to install spacepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72368433/note-this-error-originates-from-a-subprocess-and-is-likely-not-a-problem-with) :

```
conda create -n <name>
conda activate <name>
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
conda install python=3.8
```

However, when I run "conda config --env --set subdir osx-64"

I got this error message:

```
CondaValueError: Key 'subdir' is not a known primitive parameter.
```

So I am trying to upgrade my Conda to the latest version or at least `conda 4.12.0` so  that I can run `--set subdir osx-64` following the instructions below

[How do I update Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda)

But no matter what I did,

```
conda update conda
conda update -n root conda
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

My conda still got stuck at `conda 4.5.11` and `conda config --env --set subdir osx-64` still gives me the error

`CondaValueError: Key 'subdir' is not a known primitive parameter.`

could some help?

Comment: Have you found a solution to that problem?